# Python library to use rank-decomposed tensors in abstracted form

Tags: python, tensor

I'm dealing with a bunch of high-order tensors that I know have massive rank redundancy.  I would like to do something like the following:

```
import some_library

T1 = some_inhouse_code(args1)   # eg, returns some high-rank numpy.ndarray (2 to 6 indices)
T2 = some_inhouse_code(args2)   # eg, returns some high-rank numpy.ndarray (2 to 6 indices)

T1_d = some_library.decompose_tensor(T1, some_specs)   # performs rank decomposition
T2_d = some_library.decompose_tensor(T2, some_specs)   # performs rank decomposition

# result = numpy.tensordot(T1, T2, contraction_axes)            # this would be slow
result_d = some_library.tensordot(T1_d, T2_d, contraction_axes)   # this is much faster
```

The function `some_library.decompose_tensor` would apply something like a CP or Tucker decomposition to its argument (according to supplied specs about rank, etc) and return some abstraction containing that info, which can be used in its place during algebraic manipulations.

Of course, I will also need the inverse functions to rebuild explicit tensors from their abstracted forms.

I've looked through the documentation of a few libraries but not seeing anything that looks this simple (maybe because it can't be made this simple?).